# Upload picture NO plugin NO activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, upload, controller

i want to create a function into my controller to save a picture uploaded by an admin. I don't want to use plugin or Activerecord, just a function to write the bytes of the picture into the directory app/assets/images/ .
So , when the admin create a new product he puts the picture of the product into the app.
I want to use this function in the action `create` of the `Product Controller`.
In this way , before to save in the db the new product , the picture will be saved into the app (not in the db, i want just to write bytes).
I searched on internet and i founded a function to save picture.
I have a strange error : `undefined method`read' for "picture.png":String`
Here all my things:

edit.html.erb

```
<h1>Editing product</h1>

<%= render 'form' ,:multipart => true%>

<%= link_to 'Show', @product %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', products_path %>
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>
  <% if @product.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :image_url %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :image_url %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :upload %><br>
        <%= file_field :upload, :datafile %></p>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

product_controller.rb

```
  def create

        name =  params[:upload][:datafile]
    directory = Rails.root.join('app', 'assets','images')
    # create the file path
    path = File.join(directory, name)
    # write the file
    File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(params[:upload][:datafile].read) }


    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

[image]
thank you for the help.

EDIT: new error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `form_for`, the actual temp file will be in `params[:product][:upload]`. Try this

Within the `_form.html.erb` partial, change the `file_field` line to

```
<%= file_field :upload %>
```

Then, within your `create` action

```
name = params[:product][:upload].original_filename
directory = Rails.root.join('app', 'assets','images')
# create the file path
path = File.join(directory, name)
# write the file
File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(params[:product][:upload].read) }
```

Comment: hi, thank for th answer . i did it but i have this error: ArgumentError in Products#new wrong number of arguments (1 for 2..3). I post a new screen on the main post

Comment: i have to put : '<%= f.file_field :upload %>' instead of '<%= file_field :upload %>'. But now i have this error: ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in ProductsController#create unknown attribute: upload

Comment: @Vito - that's because `upload` is not an attribute of your `products` model. Change `@product = Product.new(product_params)` to `@product = Product.new(product_params.except(:upload))` and that should work.